# Python libraries for correlating Photo to GPX file?

Tags: python, coordinates, gpx, photos, geotag

Can anyone recommend a Python library(s) that can geotag a photograph with the lat/long coordinates by correlating the timestamp of the photograph to the timestamp of a waypoint within a GPX file?

I am aware of desktop applications like [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/en/) which will do this for you, but I would like to write an automation procedure that I could run on a nightly basis that emulates this process:

1. User takes a GPS and a camera into the field.
2. User drops a folder onto a server with a GPX file and the photos taken that day.
3. A Python process geotags the metadata each photo in the folder with the lat/long coordinates by comparing the photo timestamp to the nearest equivalent timestamp (+/- 30 seconds?) of a waypoint in the GPX file.
4. Convert the coordinates found in the photo's metadata to a point in a GIS system.

I have procedures in place for steps 1, 2, & 4 but either need to find a library that already accomplishes step 3 or write my own.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use [Exiv2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python) to edit the images' metadata and just write your on function where you grab the two timestamps and compare them.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with writing to the EXIF metadata.  The existence of a pre-built comparison library is what I am most interested.  No need to re-invent the wheel if it already exists.

Comment: You could have a look at the source code of the command-line utility [HappyCamel](http://happycamel.sourceforge.net/) or at [GPicSync](http://code.google.com/p/gpicsync/), which are both written in Python. There are several ready-to-use command-line tools specified on this [list of geocoding software](http://code.google.com/p/gpicsync/wiki/OtherGeocodingSoftware), if non-Python is an option. A widely used command line utility is the [gpsPhoto Perl Script](http://www.carto.net/projects/photoTools/gpsPhoto/) which makes use of [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) library.

Answer (score 2):

On the ArcGIS stack, there is the [Match Photos To Rows By Time](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Match_Photos_To_Rows_By_Time/001700000166000000/) which you can use after you've [imported your GPX files as point feature classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000050000000). From there if you need the GPS fix back in the EXIF tags, you could use [pexif](https://github.com/bennoleslie/pexif) on the original files.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  Looks like this is available at 10.1 also.  I had used the [GeoTagged Photos To Points sample](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1cfeb0e0b8b946239ad10552eec5a21e) and included ExifUtils.py to generate points from the photos (step 4 above) but pexif looks pretty simple.  I will look into it.